# When can we plug in values in a limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

When is it that we can plug in the limit point into the function to evaluate a limit?

I believe for real limit points, we can do this when the function is continuous at the point. But what about for limits at $ \infty $ and $ -\infty $? Is there a general statement that we can make about this?

**Example**: It is easy to believe that the following limit evaluates to $ 0 $
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt{n^2+n}-n} $$

How can we not fall into these traps?

EDIT: Yes, the above limit is simple to evaluate correctly (it's $ 1/2 $). But what I'm asking is for a rigorous condition under which we can know whether or not we can naively plug in the value to get the correct answer.

Comment: There is a number system called "Riemann sphere" where "plug in $\infty$" can be done.  But even in that case, $\infty - \infty$ is undefined.  Or (as they say in calculus) indeterminate.

Comment: @tskuzzy: The problem here is not "plugging in" or "not plugging in"; the problem here is that you get an indeterminate form, namely $\infty-\infty$. If you *don't* get an indeterminate form, then you're fine. For example, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} - n$ *does* evaluate to "$1-\infty=-\infty$", because $c-\infty$ is not indeterminate.

Comment: @Arturo: What about the case where the indeterminate form is encountered "at the end"? For example, the limit laws apply to $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left({n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-n}\right)$$ which equals $\infty\cdot 1 - \infty$. Why does one not conclude that the limit does not exist in this case? Does an indeterminate form always mean that another approach needs to be taken?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: No, the limit law that says that the limit of a difference is the difference of the limits when they both exist most definitely **does not** apply to that limit. What makes you think it does?

Comment: @Arturo: Working outward: $1/n\to0$, so $\sqrt{{1}+{1/n}}\to 1$, so $n\sqrt{{1}+{1/n}}\to \infty \cdot 1$. Where am I going wrong? Is it because $L=\infty$ [isn't really a limit](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66222/how-can-mathop-lim-limits-x-to-inftyxx-space-sin2-x-exist-if-mat) in the sense of the limit law?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Because when we say that the limit is infinity, we are really saying that the limit *does not exist*, but we are saying *why* it doesn't exist. In any case, I don't see what the issue is: this gives you an indeterminate form in the extended reals: you get $\infty-\infty. The very nature of "indeterminate forms" is that you cannot conclude, simply from the form you get, whether the limit exists or not. So from that analysis you cannot conclude whether the limit exists or not. Note that indeterminate forms can **only** be encountered "at the end". So what is the issue?

Comment: @Arturo: So would it be correct to say that I can get as far as $\infty\cdot 1- \infty$, but having got there, I can conclude nothing about the limit, since I've arrived at an indeterminate form? Or have I made my error earlier than that?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Indeed, having reached $\infty-\infty$, you cannot conclude anything and you need some other method for evaluating the limit. (Note: $\infty\cdot 1$ is not indeterminate: it's $\infty$; so you simply get $\infty-\infty$).

Comment: @Arturo: And just to make sure: We've only been able to make progress (on my example and on the one in your first comment above) by using some of the propositions in your answer (since the "limit law" is not applicable in either case). Correct?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: My propositions below don't apply because you aren't looking at a composition in which the "inside" function goes to $\infty$: the square root is a composition, but the "inside" goes to $1$. The product $n\sqrt{1+(1/n)}$ is a product, not a composition. And the difference is not a composition. My "propositions below" don't apply at all.

Comment: @Arturo: Sorry. My point was that the "limit law" does not apply to either example and that other propositions about products or differences or compositions are needed (and exist) for cases where part goes to $\infty$.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: I know I am confused about just what you are going at; I think *you* are also quite confused about what you are trying to say. There are lots of limits laws; there are also rules for dealing with limits that take values in the "extended reals"; being that there are so many, I have no way of knowing which particular you may happen to be thinking about. None of the "propositions" in my answer apply to the case you are dealing with, and the results about the "extended reals" lead to an indeterminate form.

Comment: @Arturo: No you're not confused-you've got it exactly right. It's my fault. To simplify: Assume that the only limits I know about are those defined by the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition for limits in $\mathbb{R}$. Also assume that the only "limit laws" I know are those for differences, sums, products, and quotients of such limits. Imagine my puzzlement when I encounter statements like "the limit is $\infty$" and by manipulations like those above. But I now see that there are _other_ limit rules, in particular rules that apply for limits in the extended reals. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, I don't think you actually asked what you meant to ask. I'll answer what you actually asked, and then comment on what I think you meant to ask.

You are correct that if $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x) = k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ is continuous at $k$, then
$$\lim_{x\to a}\;g(f(x)) = g\left(\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\right) = g(k);$$
and this also holds if $a$ is replaced by $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

It gets a bit trickier if the limit of $f$ is $\infty$ or $-\infty$; for one thing, it no longer makes sense to write $g(\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x))$, so instead we must talk about $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}g(t)$. But even with that correction, we do not have an easy criteria for when it makes sense to "plug in"; here are two propositions and one example along those lines.

**Proposition 1.** If $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x) = \infty$, and $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}g(t) = k\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\;g(f(x))=k$.

*Proof.* Suppose $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}g(t) = k$. First, take $k\in\mathbb{R}$. We show that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\;g(f(x)) = k$. Let $\epsilon\gt 0$. Then there exists $M\gt 0$ such that if $t\gt M$, then $|g(t)-k|\lt \epsilon$. Since $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x) = \infty$, there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that if $0\lt |x-a|\lt \delta$, then $f(x)\gt M$. Thus, if $0\lt |x-a|\lt \delta$, then $f(x)\gt M$, hence $|g(f(x))-k|\lt\epsilon$. Therefore, $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\;g(f(x)) = k$, as claimed.

Now consider the case $k=\infty$. Let $N\gt 0$; then there exists $M\gt 0$ such that if $t\gt M$, then $g(t)\gt N$. Since $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$, there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that if $0\lt |x-a|\lt \delta$, then $f(x)\gt M$; hence $g(f(x))\gt N$ whenever $0\lt |x-a|\lt \delta$, proving that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\;g(f(x))=\infty$. The same argument holds if $k=-\infty$. **QED**

The result also holds if $a$ is replaced with $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

The converse doesn't work in general:

**Example:** Functions $f$ and $g$, with $g$ continuous everywhere (in fact, uniformly continuous), $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$, $\lim\limits_{x\to a} \;g(f(x))$ exists, and $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}g(t)$ does not exist.

Let $f(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor\pi$, $g(t)=\sin(t)$, $a=\infty$. Then $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\;g(f(x))=0$, but $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}g(t)$ does not exist, nor is it equal to $\infty$ or $-\infty$.  It is not hard to come up with similar examples with $a\in\mathbb{R}$. **QED**

On the other hand, with a bit more information, we have:

**Proposition 2.** Let $f$ and $g$ be functions, and assume that:

1. $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$; and
2. For every $\delta\gt 0$ there exists $M_{\delta}\gt 0$ such that $(M_{\delta},\infty)\subseteq f\Bigl( (a-\delta,a)\cup(a,a+\delta)\Bigr)$.

If $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\;g(f(x))=k\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$, then $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}g(t) = k$.

*Proof.* We do the case $k\in\mathbb{R}$; the other two cases are similar. Let $\epsilon\gt 0$. Then there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that if $0\lt|x-a|\lt \delta$, then $|g(f(x))-k|\lt\epsilon$.

By (2), there exists $M_{\delta}$ such if $t\gt M_{\delta}$, then there exists $x\in (a-\delta,a)\cup(a,a+\delta)$ with $f(x)=t$.

Therefore, if $t\gt M$, then there exists $x$, $0\lt |x-a|\lt \delta$ such that $g(t) = g(f(x))$, hence $|g(t)-k| = |g(f(x))-k|\lt \epsilon$, with the last inequality by choice of $\delta$. Therefore, $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}g(t)=k$, as claimed. **QED**

Similar results hold if we replace $a$ with $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

**Corollary.** Let $f$ and $g$ be functions with $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x) =\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\;g(f(x))=k\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$. If $f$ is continuous on an open punctured neighborhood of $a$, then $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\;g(t)=k$.

*Proof.* If $f$ is continuous on an open punctured neighborhood of $a$, then the condition that $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to a$ ensures that $f$ satisfies condition 2 of Proposition 2. **QED**

In fact, it's enough that $f$ be continuous on either an interval of the form $(a-\delta_f,a)$, *or* on an interval of the form $(a,a+\delta_f)$.

Continuity can even be weakened further:

**Corollary.** Let $f$ and $g$ be functions with $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\;g(f(x))=k\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$. If there exists $\delta_f\gt 0$ such that $f$ has the intermediate value property on either $(a-\delta_f,a)$ or on $(a,a+\delta_f)$, then $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} g(t) = k$.

*Proof.* Assume that $f$ has the intermediate value property on $(a-\delta_f,a)$; the other case is similar. We prove that $f$ satisfies condition (2) of Proposition 2.

Let $\delta\gt 0$; we may assume that $\delta\leq\delta_f$.

Let $M=f(a-\frac{\delta}{2})$; let $z\gt M$. Since $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\;f(x)=\infty$, there exist $x_1$, $a-\frac{\delta}{2}\lt x_1 \lt a$ such that $f(x_1)\gt z$. Since $f$ has the intermediate value property on $(a-\delta,a)$ and $f(a-\frac{\delta}{2})\lt z\lt f(x_1)$, we can find $x_2\in (a-\frac{\delta}{2},x_1)$ such that $f(x_2)= z$; thus, $z\in f(a-\delta,a)$. This proves that for all $z\gt M$, $z\in f(a-\delta,a)$, hence $(M,\infty)$ is contained in the image and Condition (2) of Proposition 2 holds; conclusion of the corollary now follows from Proposition 2.  **QED**

Note that in my example above, $f$ does not have the intermediate value property, which is what leads to problems.

---

That said: the *real* issue with your example lies in the indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$, rather than a problem with "plugging in", I think.

Instead, what you are dealing with here is an attempt at applying the **limit laws** that say, for example, that the limit of a difference is the difference of the limits:

> If $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)=M$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\Bigl(f(x)-g(x)\Bigr) = L-M$.

If we try to extend this (and related results on sums, products, and quotients) to the cases where limits are equal to $\infty$ or $-\infty$, then you have to deal with the *extended reals*, $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$. The problem here is that not every operation among extended reals is *well-defined*. Some operations are well defined and the limits laws work for them:

- $\infty+a = \infty$ for all real numbers $a$;
- $-\infty+a = -\infty$ for all real numbers $a$;
- $\pm\infty\times a =\pm\infty$ if $a\gt 0$ or $a=\infty$;
- $\pm\infty\times a = \mp\infty$ if $a\lt 0$ or $a=-\infty$;
- $\frac{\pm\infty}{a} = \pm\infty$ if $a\gt 0$;
- $\frac{\pm\infty}{a} = \mp\infty$ if $a\lt 0$;
- $\frac{a}{\pm\infty} = 0$.

But other expressions are *indeterminate forms*: the limit laws don't apply to them. They don't apply to expressions like $\infty-\infty$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ (just like they don't apply in the real numbers to expressions like $\frac{a}{0}$).

So the problem is not one of "plugging in", but rather that the mistake you mention lies in trying to apply the limit laws and forgetting that $\infty-\infty$ is an **indeterminate form** and not an operation that can be performed.

Comment: @The Chaz: Thanks; though on reflection it seems to me that the OP was not asking what he actually meant to ask, what really addresses the issue of the example in question. I've expanded the answer to include that (as well as weakened the hypothesis of the second proposition along the way).

Comment: +1 yet another amazing answer.  Wish I could do +more, for what it's worth ($\epsilon $)

Comment: @Ross: It's worth *epsilon* ?!?

Comment: @The Chaz: (and Arturo) Sorry, I menat the rep is worth $\epsilon$.  The answer is worth much more.

Comment: I should say so! It's worth *at least* $\delta$ :)

Comment: I keep seeing these excerpts of the book "Everything I Wished I was Taught in Math" by Arturo Magidin, yet I can't seem to find the book anywhere... when is it coming out, and if it does come out, where can I buy a copy?

Comment: @J.M. Well, as my just-completed edit shows, it needs to go through several rounds of refereeing...

Answer (score 3):

For $x\to\pm\infty$, consider the change of variables $u=1/x$ and let $u\to 0^{\pm}$.

Comment: That's a method of evaluating such limits. But how can we use this to know that we can simply plug in $ 0^\pm $?

Comment: @tskuzzy, you can when the function $f(u)$ is continuous at 0.

Comment: Are you trying to say "never"? Because $ f(u) $ is always undefined at 0 and thus discontinuous.

Comment: The function is continuous at 0 in this case is a shorthand phrase for: there exists a continuous extension to 0.

Comment: @tskuzzy: What Ihf means is that even if the function is not defined at zero, thus discontinuous, the disctontinuity might be removable...Keep in mind that after you do some algebraic manipulations/simplifications sometimes you obtain expressions which are defined at 0.

Comment: Doesn't that imply that the limit at $0^\pm$ are equal and thus the limits at $\pm\infty$ are equal as well? Why is that a necessary condition?

Comment: Yes, I meant that the discontinuity might be removable.

Answer (score 0):

In this case its rather easy to see if you notice that

$$\sqrt{n^2+n}-n=\sqrt{n^2+n+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}}-n = \sqrt{(n+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}}-n$$

In general, I think the best thing to do is to expand it into a polynomial, and look at what the resulting structure looks like.

Comment: I know the correct way of evaluating the above limit. But how can we avoid evaluating it the wrong way? Under what conditions can we rigorously show that a limit can/cannot be evaluated by plugging in the value?

Comment: I sort of mentioned it later in my statement. You would want to expand it and see what the terms are. In this case you would have something like $n+\frac{1}{2}+... - n$

Comment: To me, that still seems more like an algorithm or a heuristic to evaluate it. But what if I gave you the limit $ \frac{n+0.5}{n} $? Clearly it's 0 via plugging in $ \infty $. In general, why is it that we can do this for certain classes of limits?

Comment: you cannot in general "plug in" $\infty$, you would have you apply l'hopitals in that case to know (if its a fraction)

Comment: Actually I think I understand your question. Are you asking if $\infty-\infty=0$? Which is obviously false. In the question you posted, you get $\infty-\infty$ if you just plug in. Which you cannot evaluate.

Comment: @tskuzzy: I imagine you meant two comments ago that the limit was clearly $1$. "Plugging in" $\infty$ will almost never work. One could come up with a small number of types of problem in which it will work, but they will almost never be useful, and when they are useful, correct methods are very fast also.