# Formal basis for variable substitution in limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

So we do a lot of variable substitution in limits at school. Stuff like $\lim\limits_{x\to5}\ (x+1)^2\ =\ \lim\limits_{y\to6}\ y^2$, where we define the substitution $y = x + 1$.

But I've never been clear on what exactly the theoretical basis for this is. What is the formula that you're actually applying when you do variable substitution? What are the formal conditions under which it is possible?

My conjecture would be the following:

For all continuous $f$, and all real $a$:
$\lim\limits_{x\to a}\ (f\circ g)(x)\ =\lim\limits_{x\to g(a)}\ f(x)$, where $g$ is a continuous function

So to take my first example, $f$ would be $x^2$, $g$ would be $x + 1$, and $a$ would be $5$.

Am I in the right area? If this is correct, can it be proven using $\epsilon$-$\delta$? I had a half-hearted shot at it the other night and didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The complete story is as follows:

If the functions $g:\ A\to B$ and $f:\ B\to C$ have limits
$$\lim_{x\to\xi}g(x)=:\eta\ ,\qquad \lim_{y\to\eta}f(y)=:\zeta\ ,$$
and if  $f$ is continuous at $\eta$ in case $\eta$ occurs as value of $g$, then
$$\lim_{x\to\xi}f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=\lim_{y\to\eta} f(y)\ .$$

This holds also if any one of $\xi$, $\eta$, $\zeta$ is $\ =\infty$.

The extra condition "and if $f$ is continuous $\ldots$" is usually fulfilled, but one cannot do without it: Consider the example $g(x):\equiv 1$ and $f(y):=2$ $\ (y=1)$, $\ f(y):=3$ $\ (y\ne1)$. Then $\lim_{x\to1}f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=2$, but $\lim_{x\to1}g(x)=1$, $\ \lim_{y\to1}f(y)=3$.

Comment: So essentially, in this version, by using the limit of f rather than its exact value at a particular point, we can include cases at infinity in the theorem?

Comment: @Jack M: Yes. By the way, I have changed the rôles of $f$ and $g$, as suggested by Arturo Magidin.

Comment: I found this answer those most clear and complete. Arturo did include a proof, but this answer covers limits at infinity (to be fair though, my wording could be interpreted as only covering real limits). Also I was able to work out why a variable substitution I tried the other day failed - $f$ wasn't continuous at the limit of $g$.

Comment: 1) There is no requirement the value of $g(\xi)$ right? It can be any real number? 2) If $g(x)$ does not equal $\eta$ except possibly at $\xi$, then continuity of $f$ at $\eta$ is not required, correct? Thanks.

Comment: One more comment. The second condition states we need to know the original limit, $\lim_{y\to\eta}f(y)$, actually exists. So there are cases where after the change of variable we find $\lim_{x\to\xi}f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)$ exists, but the original $\lim_{y\to\eta}f(y)$ does not, in fact, exist? It would really useful in practice if we can say, under some condition, $\lim_{x\to\xi}f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)$ exists iff $\lim_{y\to\eta}f(y)$ exists.

Comment: What do you mean by "any one of $ξ, η, ζ$ is  $=∞$"? Can I let both $ξ=∞$ and $η=\infty$? For example, $g(x)=e^x$ and $f(x)=1/x$.

Comment: It seems to me that only holds if $\eta = \infty$. 

Since if $\xi = \infty$, consider the example given in the answer, $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(g(x)) = 2$ but $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{y \to 1} f(y) = 3$. 

For the other case, consider $f(x) = 1/x (x \ne 0)$, $f(x) = 0 (x = 0)$, $g(x) \equiv 0$, with $\xi = 0, \eta = 0, \zeta = \infty$.

Comment: @AstrickHarren If $\eta=\infty$ the result is always true. If $\eta\in\mathbb R$ we can have $\xi,\zeta$ real or $\infty$ provided that $g(x)\neq \eta$ in a punctured neighbourhood of $\xi$. So, this answer have a missing hypothesis. See a general statement with all the needed hypothesis in my answer.

Comment: What does the phrase "in case $\eta$ occurs as value of $g$" mean? (And why can't it be omitted?)

Answer (score 19):

Yes, that's essentially the idea.

But this follows from the definition of continuity: we just need to show that if $f$ is continuous at $g(a)$ and $g$ is continuous at $a$, then $f\circ g$ is continuous at $a$. Because then both sides evaluate to $f(g(a))$, by definition of continuity (which requires that the limit exist and be equal to evaluating the function at the point.

To prove that if $g$ is continuous at $a$ and $f$ is continuous at $g(a)$, then $f\circ g$ is continuous at $a$, note first that $f\circ g$ is defined at $a$. Now, let $\epsilon\gt0$. then we know that there exists $\delta_1\gt 0$ such that if $|y-g(a)|\lt\delta_1$, then $|f(y)-f(g(a))|\lt\epsilon$; this holds, because $f$ is continuous at $g(a)$.

Now, since $g$ is continuous at $a$, and $\delta_1\gt 0$, this means that there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that if $|x-a|\lt\delta$, then $|g(x)-g(a)|\lt\delta_1$.

Thus, if $|x-a|\lt\delta$, then $|g(x)-g(a)|\lt\delta_1$, and therefore $|f(g(x))-f(g(a))|=|f\circ g(x) - f\circ g(a)|\lt\epsilon$.

Thus, for all $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that if $|x-a|\lt\delta$, then $|f\circ g(x) - f\circ g(a)|\lt\epsilon$. Therefore, $f\circ g$ is continuous at $a$.

Therefore, we have that $\lim\limits_{y\to g(a)} f(y) = f(g(a))$, since $f$ is continuous at $g(a)$; and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f\circ g(x) = f\circ g(a) = f(g(a))$, since $f\circ g$ is continuous at $a$.

You don't quite need $g$ to be continuous: if $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)=L$ and $f$ is continuous at $L$, then we have
$$\lim_{x\to a}f\circ g(x) = \lim_{y\to L}f(y) = f(L).$$
To verify this, let $\epsilon\gt 0$. Then there exists $\delta_1\gt 0$ such that for all $x$, $|y-L|\lt\delta_1$ implies $|f(y)-f(L)|\lt\epsilon$. Since $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)=L$, there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that if $0\lt |x-a|\lt \delta$ then $|g(x)-L|\lt\delta_1$. So, suppose that $0\lt |x-a|\lt\delta$. Then $|g(x)-L|\lt\delta_1$, and therefore $|f(g(x))-f(L)|\lt\epsilon$. Therefore, for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that if $0\lt |x-a|\lt\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(L)|\lt\epsilon$. This proves that if $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x) = L$ and $f$ is continuous at $L$, then 
$$\lim\limits_{x\to a}f\circ g(x) = \lim\limits_{y\to L}f(y) = f(L).$$
In particular, if $g$ is continuous at $a$, then we replace $L$ with $g(a)$.

We cannot omit the continuity of $f$ at $L$, though: take $g(x) = 0$ for all $x$, and let
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 &\text{if }x\neq 0\\
0 &\text{if }x=0.
\end{array}\right.$$
Then $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(g(x)) = 0$, because $f(g(x))=f(0)=0$. But 
$$\lim\limits_{y\to 0}f(y) = 1,$$
because we never take the value $y=0$ in evaluating the limit.

One can replace continuity of $f$ with other conditions; for example, we may ask that $g$ have a limit $L$ at $a$, and moreover, that for every $\delta\gt0$ there exist an $\eta\gt 0$ such that $g$ takes all values on $(L-\eta,L+\eta)$, except perhaps $L$ itself, on $(a-\delta,a+\delta)-\{a\}$.

**Added.** The situation with limits as $x\to\infty$ is essentially the same if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ exists and is real. It is more complicated when the limit of $g$ is $\pm\infty$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53703/742) for some discussion on that.

Comment: We just need $g$ to have the limit, say $a$, at $x_0$ and $f$ has the limit, say $A$, at $a$. Of course we know that $g(x)\neq 0$ in some deleted nbh of $x_0$. Do we really need $g$ to be continuous at $x_0$?

Comment: @Babak: No, that's not enough. Say $g$ is constant $0$, and $f$ is $0$ at $0$, and $1$ elsewhere. Then $g$ has a limit of $a=0$ at $x_0=0$, and $f$ has a limit $A=1$ at $a=0$. But $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f\circ g(x) = 0$, and $\lim\limits_{y\to g(0)}f(y) = 1$. Replace the $0$ and $1$ with over values if you want $g(x)\neq 0$ in a punctured neighborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: Thanks, I see it, although I took $g$ not to be zero near $x_0$.

Comment: Cool, nice proof. But what about limits at infinity?

Comment: @JackM: Do the results in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/53703/742) address that question?

Comment: @BabakSorouh: $g$ not being $0$ near $x_0$ is completely and utterly irrelevant. $0$ is a red herring. We are not taking quotients, we are composing, so values of $0$ are irrelevant. Just add $25$ to the values I gave: take $g$ to be constant $25$, take $f$ to be $25$ at $25$ and $26$ elseewhere. Then $g$ has limit $a=25$ at $x_0=25$, and $f$ has limit $A=26$ at $a=25$. But $\lim\limits_{x\to 25}f\circ g(x)=25$ and $\lim\limits_{y\to 25}f(y) = 26$.

Comment: Arturo, correct me if I'm wrong. But I think the difference in $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(g(x))$ and $\lim\limits_{y \to L} f(y)$ (where $L= \lim\limits_{x \to a } g(x)$) is that, in the former limit, $g(x)$ could be constant in the deleted nbh of $a$ whereas the latter notation doesn't cover that, i.e it only talks about what happens to $f$ when $y$ is in the deleted nbh of $L$, and not when $y$ is constant there (in which $f(y)$ is simply constant).

Comment: So my point is, of course continuity of $f$ on $L$ would fix that but I don't suppose we have to go that far, do we? In that, I mean the equality $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(g(x))= \lim\limits_{y \to L} f(y)$ holds if $g(x)$ is not constant in the deleted nbh of $a$. Do you agree?

Comment: @William: The paragraph at the end, before "**Added:**" explicitly says you can replace continuity with other conditions, and the situation you specify is included in the sample condition I gave there 9 years ago.

Comment: Coming back to this after reviewing some analysis notes. In the paragraph where you've mentioned, "replacing continuity of $f$ by <conditions that require $g$ to not be a constant in near $x=a$>". From what I infer, these conditions only imply that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(g(x)) =\lim\limits_{g(x) \to L}f(g(x))$, now to show that these limits also equal $f\left(\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x) \right)$, you also need another condition that $f$ is defined on the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)= L$, which doesn't follow from the mew conditions, I don't think?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(g(x)) =\lim\limits_{g(x) \to L}f(g(x))$ can exist without having the case that $f\left(\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x) \right)$ exists. For example, $f(x) = x$ for $x ≠e^3$ and $g(x) = e^x, x ≠ 3$ then $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(g(x)) =\lim\limits_{g(x) \to L}f(g(x))=e^3$ but $f\left(\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x) \right)$ is undefined. What did I miss?

Comment: Well actually now that I think about it, you need more than just $f$ is defined on $L$. Because I can just define $f(L)=$ some random number not equal to the limit.

Comment: @William: The condition I describe is much stronger than "is not constant near $a$". Saying to takes all values on the interval implies it is not constant, but it implies a **lot** more than just "is not constant".

Comment: Really? I'll be honest. Before commenting, I must've read that statement a hundred times. Let me break it down so maybe you can point out what I'm actually missing. We have $\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)= L$ and you can get as close to $a$ as you want by choosing any $\delta>0$, and you'll still find at least one interval $(L- \eta, L+ \eta)$ for some suitable $\eta >0$ such that $g$ takes all the values in that interval except maybe $L$. But all of this is about $g$. How does this establish that $f$ is also defined at $L$ and $f(L)$ equals those limits? $g$ is my example, satisfies that,no?

Comment: @William: the function $g(x)$ whose value is $x$ at rationals and $0$ at irrationals is not constant on any interval surrounding $0$, has a limit at $0$, but does **not** take all values between $-\eta$ and $\eta$ for any $\eta\gt0$.  Your assertion that the existence of the limit implies "takes all values" is quite simply false.

Comment: Wait. That's not what I was implying. Existence of limit implies take all values is obviously false. The simplest example is a constant function. I meant that as an "if we have a function with $g(x)$ with $\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)=L$ and so-on"... Maybe a poor wording, sorry but I was just trying to use your words in that paragraph.

Comment: @William. Still: that's a function with a limit, which is not constant on any interval containing zero; but because it "skips over" values in any interval,you can pair it with a function that will mess you up on composition. Again, the condition that it takes all values is much stronger than just "is non constant", even when paired with the existence of a limit and the other conditions.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure you're right. But *why* is it stronger? What other things is it implying is what I want to know. I feel like there is definitely some very important detail I'm overlooking. (Yes, the example of $g(x)$ you gave is actually pretty nice now that I've drawn it's graph and see the point you were trying to make earlier.)

Comment: @William:The idea there is just that when you are trying to find the limit of $f(g(x))$, things may "work out" because $g$ "skips over" any bad points that $f$ may have near $L=\lim g(x)$. And that might mess you up when you try to do $\lim_{x\to L}f(x)$. The condition I give ensures that the composition "hides nothing" that is happening near $L$ for $f$. Continuity of $f$ at $L$ similarly ensures that there is nothing weird for $f$ near $L$ that may be hidden by the composition.

Comment: @William: What the condition implies is that $g$ is always *surjective* near near $L$; so that when you look at the limit of the composition, it is always forcing you to consider *all* values that $f$ takes for inputs near $L$. That is *precisely* what you need to do when you are trying to find the limit $\lim_{x\to L}f(x)$, but not necessarily when you are trying to find the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))$.

Comment: @William: The main difference between $\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))$ and $\lim_{x\to L}f(x)$, when $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=L$, is that in the first you only need to consider the values that $f(x)$ takes near $L$ *in the range of $g(x)$*, whereas in the latter you need to consider the values that $f(x)$ takes *everywhere* near $L$. Any condition that ensures wither that "all values near $L$" are also in the range of $g(x)$, or that just looking at the ones in the range of $g$ will not mess you up, will give you equality of limits.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience. I understand now, you're saying that if takes if $g$ takes all the values near $L$ then $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(g(x)) = \lim\limits_{y \to L} f(y)= K$ because we want $y=g(x)$ to satisfy $0<|y-L|<\eta \implies |f(y)-K|< ϵ $ definition of limit. But notice that you say $g$ takes all values near $L$ **except possibly** $L$. So I'm asking how does $K = f(L) = f(\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x))$ part follow from whatever we have assumed. For what it's worth, $f$ may not even be defined at $y=L$. (Thank you once again for your time and efforts. I'm grateful.)

Comment: @William: If $\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))=M$, and $g$ has the given property, we want to show that $\lim_{y\to L}f(x) = M$. Let $\epsilon\lt 0$. We know that there exists $\delta_1$ such that $0\lt|x-a|\lt \delta_1$ implies $|f(g(x))-M|\lt\epsilon$, and there is an $\eta\gt 0$ such that $g(x)$ takes all values on $(L-\eta,L+\eta)$ except perhaps $\eta$. Pick $\delta=\eta$. I claim that $0\lt |y-L|\lt \delta$ implies $|f(y)-M|\lt\epsilon$. For if $0\lt|y-L|\lt\delta$, then $y\in(L-\eta,y+\eta)$, $y\neq L$ (cont)

Comment: @William: (cont) And therefore there is an $x$ in $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ such that $g(x)=y$. Therefore, $|f(g(x))-M||\lt\epsilon$. But that means $|f(y)-M|\lt\epsilon$, which is what we needed to prove.

Comment: @William: If your confusion was about $f(L)$ (as opposed to whatever value $\lim f(g(x))$ may have), then I hope this clarifies it. Because it is an off-hand comment and not a formal statement/proof, I was less than precise when I wrote that paragraph, and was just trying to given an idea of an example of a type of condition one might impose instead of continuity of $f$.

Comment: The question of @William is about the value of $f(L)$, not $\lim\limits_{y\to L}f(y)$. Surjectivity of $g$ does nothing to fix this; take $g(x) = x$ (which is indeed surjective around $0$) and $f(x) = x$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0) = 100$. Then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}g(x) = 0$, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(g(x))=0$, $\lim\limits_{y\to 0}f(y)=0$ but $f(0)=100$.

Comment: @TSF I think I only clued into that late. The original question asked for the equality of $\lim_{x\to a}(f\circ g)(x)$ and $\lim_{y\to g(a)} f(y)$. So I was refering to results giving equality between $\lim_{x\to a}(f\circ g)(x)$ and $\lim_{y\to L}f(x)$ where $\lim_{x\to a}g(x) =L$. But I was less than clear, apparently.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood. Since, you go from showing $\lim\limits_{x \to a }f(g(x))= \lim\limits_{y \to L}f(y)= f(L)$ immediately to "One can replace the continuity of $f$...". So I finally asked a question on the site because I didn't want to annoy the hell out of you haha.

Comment: @William: Not your fault; as I said, this was an off-hand remark towards the end and was less than clear.

Answer (score 6):

While this is a fairly old question, I stumbled upon it and wanted to give a different take for the case where the continuity of $f$ cannot be assumed. To make things work, then, we need to strengthen the hypotheses on $g$.

**Theorem.** Suppose $g$ is continuous and injective on an open interval $I$ containing $a$ and $f$ is some function. Then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}{(f \circ g)(x)}$ exists if and only if $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to g(a)}{f(t)}$ exists, and they are equal when they do exist.

*Proof.* Suppose $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}{f(g(x))} = L$. We claim that $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to g(a)}{f(t)} = L$. To that effect, let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Our hypothesis means that there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(g(x)) - L| < \epsilon.$$
Because $g$ is one-to-one and continuous on an open interval $I$, $g^{-1}$ is also one-to-one and continuous on the open interval $g[I]$. Thus, there exists a $\gamma>0$ such that
$$|t - g(a)| < \gamma \implies |g^{-1}(t) - a| < \delta.$$
Because $g^{-1}(t) = a$ only occurs when $t=g(a)$, we similarly have
$$0 < |t - g(a)| < \gamma \implies 0 < |g^{-1}(t) - a| < \delta.$$
Thus, for all $t$,
$$0 < |t - g(a)| < \gamma \implies 0 < |g^{-1}(t) - a| < \delta \implies |f(g(g^{-1}(t))) - L| < \epsilon$$
or
$$0 < |t - g(a)| < \gamma \implies |f(t) - L| < \epsilon.$$
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to g(a)}{f(t)} = L$.

The opposite direction follows from the above direction: if we let $h = f \circ g$ and $b=g(a)$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to g(a)}{f(t)}$ may be written as $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to b}{h(g^{-1}(t))}$, and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}{f(g(x))}$ may be written as $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to g^{-1}(b)}{h(x)}$. Since $g^{-1}$ satisfies the same hypotheses as $g$ and there were no requirements on $f$, the above argument goes through in this new arrangement. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is treated in [Protter's book](https://www.google.com.br/books/edition/A_First_Course_in_Real_Analysis/XVjdBwAAQBAJ?hl=pt-BR&gbp) (see from theorem 2.7 to theorem 2.17(a)). A general result can be stated as follows.

> **Theorem of change of variables in limits:** Let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ represent real numbers, $\infty$ or $-\infty$. We have
> $$\lim_{x\to\alpha} f(g(x))=\lim_{y\to \beta}f(y),\quad\text{where}\quad \beta=\lim_{x\to\alpha} g(x),$$
> provid that $\displaystyle\lim_{y\to \beta}f(y)=\gamma$ **and** at least one of the following conditions is satisfied:
>
> 1. $\beta,\gamma\in \mathbb R$ and $f$ is continuous at $\beta$.
> 2. $\beta\in\mathbb R$ and $g(x)\neq \beta$ in a punctured neighbourhood of $\alpha$.
> 3. $\beta=\infty$ or $-\infty$.
>
> The same result is valid for one-sided limits.

See the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4692315/70305).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my point of view. Let $f:\text{D}_f\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\text{D}_g\to \text{R}_g$ be functions with $\text{R}_g\subseteq\text{D}_f$ so that $f\circ g:\text{D}_g\to\mathbb{R}$ is well defined. Well, I assume that you are aware of the following theorem.

> **Theorem 1.** If $g$ is continuous at $a$ and $f$ is continuous at $b=g(a)$ then $f\circ g$ is continuous at $a$. In terms of limit notation, if $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=g(a)$ and $\lim_{x\to b}f(x)=f(b)$ then we have $\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))=f(g(a))$.

A slight generalization of this theorem is the following

> **Theorem 2.** Suppose that $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=b$ and $\lim_{x\to b}f(x)=c$. Furthemore, assume that $g$ satisfies the following condition
> $$\exists r>0,\,\,\,0<|x-a|<r\implies 0<|g(x)-b|.$$
> Then we have $\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))=c$.

We can also express another variation of **Theorem 1** as below.

> **Theorem 3.** Suppose that $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=b$ and $\lim_{x\to b}f(x)=f(b)$ so $f$ is continuous at $b$. Then we have $\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))=f(b)$.

**Remark 1.** Theorem 3 is simply saying that when the outer function is continuous, you can pass the limit inside, provided that the inside limit exist. Note that there is no assumption on the continuity of the inner function. The easy form to remember is $\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))=f(\lim_{x\to a}g(x))$.

**Remark 2.** Sometimes, instead of writing $\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))=c$, we use the more intuitive symbolism of $\lim_{g(x)\to b}f(g(x))=c$.

**Remark 3.** These theorems can naturally be generalized for metric spaces.

In your example, we have $f:x\mapsto x^2$ and $g:x\mapsto x+1$, $a=5$, $b=6$. We clearly have $\lim_{x\to5}x+1=6$ and $\lim_{x\to 6}x^2=36$. More importantly, choose $r=1$ so whenever $0<|x-5|<1$ we have that $|(x+1)-6|>0$. These two imply that $\lim_{x\to 5}(x+1)^2=36$. In practice, one usually write this as

$$\lim_{x\to 5}(x+1)^2=\lim_{y\to 6}y^2=36.$$

What happens in the mind of calculus students is that they detect $g:x\mapsto x+1$ instantly, compute $\lim_{x\to 5}x+1=6$ in their (unconscious) mind and get the first equality which is then easily computed to get the second one. One tricky point about this is that as you do the writing from left to right, you may think that the implications are also in this order while it is exactly in the opposite direction, right to left! Also, $y$ here is just a dummy variable and can be replaced with other variables such as $t$ or the $x$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L_1 = \lim\limits_{x \to g(a)} f(x)$ and $L_2 = \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(g(x))$.  $L_1$ is unique in $\mathbb{R}$ so that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta_1(\varepsilon) > 0$ such that if $|x-g(a)| < \delta_1(\varepsilon)$ then $|f(x) - L_1| < \varepsilon$.  Similarly $L_2$ is unique so that there exists $\delta_2(\varepsilon) > 0$ such that if $|x-a| < \delta_2(\varepsilon)$ then $|f(g(x)) - L_2| < \varepsilon$.

Now we will show that $L_1$ also satisfies the property that $L_2$ satisfies uniquely.  Take $\varepsilon > 0$.  When $|x-g(a)| < \delta_1(\varepsilon/2)$,

\begin{align*}
    |f(g(x)) - L_1| &= |f(g(x)) + f(x) - f(x) - L_1| \\
    &\le |f(g(x)) - f(x)| + |f(x) - L_1| \\
    &< \varepsilon/2 + |f(g(x) - f(x)|.
  \end{align*}

Since $f$ is continuous, there exists $\delta(\varepsilon/2) > 0$ such that when $|x-g(a)| < \delta(\varepsilon/2)$, $|f(g(x)) - f(x)| < \varepsilon / 2$.  Thus if $|x - g(a)| < \min\{\delta_1(\varepsilon/2), \delta(\varepsilon/2)\}$, then we get
  \begin{align*} |f(g(x)) - L_1| < \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon. \end{align*}
Thus $L_1$ is also the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(g(x))$ and by uniqueness we conclude $L_1 = L_2$, i.e. $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(g(x)) = \lim\limits_{x\to g(a)} f(x)$.