# Limit as t approaches 0 of $-\sin(\pi t)/(t)$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Sorry I am a highschool student who isn't too good at math.

I know that the limit $\sin(t)/(t)$ as $t$ approaches 0 is 1. But how in the world would I evaluate

$$-\sin(πt)/(t)$$

as $t$ approches 0. I have not yet L'Hospital's rule yet so would there be an approach? Is it possible to factor out π from sin(πx)?

Comment: If $t$ approaches $0$, where does $\pi t$ approach? Where then, does $-\pi.(sin(\pi t)/(\pi t))$ approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

${\sin{\pi t}\over t}=\pi{\sin{\pi t}\over \pi t}$

If we nos set $u=\pi t$ we get

$${\sin{\pi t}\over t}=\pi{\sin{u}\over u}$$

And $u\to 0$ when $t\to 0$ so ${\sin{u}\over u}\to 1$. We therefore have

$$\lim_{t\to 0}{\sin{\pi t}\over t}=\pi$$

Comment: Does this not require $\sin u/u$ to be continuous at $0$? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/167948/642262).

Comment: The function defined by $f(t)=\sin{t}/t$ when $t\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$ is continuous

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for $\omega\neq 0$ we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin \omega t}{t}&=\omega\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin \omega t}{\omega t}\\
&=\omega\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\qquad\text{Where }\,\,\,x=\omega t\\
&=\omega(1)\\
&=\omega
\end{align}

Then
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\left(-\frac{\sin \pi t}{t}\right)=\ldots?$$

Answer (score 0):

You cannot factor $\pi$ out but you are close. You can do a change of variables. Assume that $u=\pi t$ (equivalently $t=u/\pi$). So as $t\to0$ we also have $u\to0$. Then
$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{-\sin(\pi t)}{t}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{-\sin(u)}{u/\pi}=(-\pi)\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}=-\pi\cdot 1=-\pi.$$

Answer (score -1):

If you have learned about Taylor expansions, you could also Taylor expand about t = 0 to find the limit. Like so :

$\sin {\pi t} \approx (\pi t) - \frac{(\pi t)^3}{6} + ...$

Substituting this in to your original expression and only taking the first term in the above approximation,

$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}-\frac{\sin {\pi t}}{t} \approx \lim_{t\rightarrow0}-\frac{\left(\pi t\right)}{t} = -\pi$.

Where the last step just involves cancelling out the $t$s.

Comment: It is very unlikely that the OP has, giiven the nature of the question.