# Prove the following translation rule for limits:

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L \iff \lim_{h \to 0} f(c+h) = L$$

---

My prove for ($\implies$) was:
Let $g(h) = f(c+h)$, then we are required to show that $\lim_{h \to 0} g(h) = L$.  I went ahead and tried to prove $\lim g(h) = L$ using epsilon-delta but don't know what I am  supposed to do with $|g(h) - L|<e$. Any help would be great!

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2325202/356114).

Comment: How did you get $|g(c)-L|$ in the first place? It would be helpful to see what you have tried so far. To me it seems like I cannot fail if I just apply the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition. That of course doesn't mean that other people cannot fail, but it's not that easy to predict where other people will fail...

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=L$, this implies that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon\qquad \text{whenever}\qquad0<|x-c|<\delta.$$
Now putting $x-c=h$, the above relation reduces to
$$|f(c+h)-L|<\epsilon\qquad \text{whenever}\qquad0<|h|<\delta.$$
This means $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(c+h)=L$.

Retracing the steps backward, we get the other way implication.