# How solve this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

How to solve this? Desirable, explain in more detail. I know this should be solved by multiplying or replace a variable
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{\sqrt[4]{x}-1}.$$

Comment: set $$x=t^{12}$$

Comment: Use $x=t^{12}$ first.

Comment: Also use L'Hospital

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is $$\frac{t^4-1}{t^3-1}=\frac{(t-1)(t+1)(t^2+1)}{(t-1)(t^2+t+1)}$$
use $$a^3-b^3=(a-b) \left(a^2+a b+b^2\right)$$

Comment: What's formula you use for numerator?

Comment: I used this formula for denominator, but i dont understand how it work for numerator, if there 4n degree?

Comment: Again, the substitution can only be made if we already know that the outer function is continuous: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167926/formal-basis-for-variable-substitution-in-limits And for that you at least need to know that the limit exists before doing the substitution. This is formally incorrect. Or am I missing something?

Comment: In our university, lecturer did not talk about such restrictions.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov Well, ask him about that. Maybe he doesn't know it himself. :D In the link I've posted there's a counterexample where the substitution technique fails when the outer function is not continuous. So unless you can prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{\sqrt[4]{x}-1}$ exists (so that the function can be extended to a continuous one) **before** doing the substitution then the posted solution is incorrect. Or that the substitution is somehow valid in that case.

Answer (score 2):

$$l = \lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{\sqrt[4]{x}-1}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{e^{\ln{\sqrt[3]{x}}}-1}{\ln\sqrt[3]{x}}\cdot\ln\sqrt[3]{x}\cdot\frac{\ln\sqrt[4]{x}}{e^{\ln\sqrt[4]{x}}-1}\cdot\frac{1}{\ln\sqrt[4]{x}}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1}{3}\cdot4\cdot\frac{\ln x}{\ln x}=\frac{4}{3}$$

With $$\lim_{f(x)\to0}\frac{e^{f(x)}-1}{f(x)}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt[12]{x}=t$.

Then $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{\sqrt[4]{x}-1}=\lim_{t\rightarrow1}\frac{t^4-1}{t^3-1}=\lim_{t\rightarrow1}\frac{4t^3}{3t^2}=\frac{4}{3}$$

Comment: That doesn't seem to be formally correct. In order to do the substitution you need to know that the outer function is continuous at $1$. And for that you need to know that limit. See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167926/formal-basis-for-variable-substitution-in-limits