# Proof that we are allowed to make substitutions to evaluate limits?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functions

Basically, if we want $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$, why are we 'allowed' to instead find the limit

$\lim_{u\to u_0}f(u)$ where $x = k(u)$, where $k(u)$ is a function in $u$ such that $\lim_{u\to u_0}k(u)= x_0$.

Sorry if this isn't precise enough.. essentially, I want to know why, for example, when we find the limit

$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$  we're allowed to instead find the limit

$\lim_{2t\to 0}f(t)$ with $x = 2t$.

I think it's trivial because it's basically 'the same limit', but I'd like to verify that intuition.

Comment: Please improve your [MatJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), it is hard to read. E.g. use `\lim_x` for $\lim_x$, `\to` for $\to$, etc.

Comment: Maybe [Formal basis for variable substitution in limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167926/formal-basis-for-variable-substitution-in-limits) helps?

Comment: It's a standard procedure and it should be available in textbooks in the same manner as sum/product/quotient rule of limits are available. The precise statement is: *if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =L$ and $\lim_{t\to b} g(t) =a$ and further $g(t) \neq a$ as $t\to b$ then $\lim_{t\to b} f(g(t)) =L$*.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh What exactly do you mean by the last line? The answer to the other question just requires f to be continuous at a.

Comment: The function f must be continuous limits must exist (not be infinity).  This is a standard theorem and it should be proven via delta epsilon proofs.  But you are absolutely correct that it should not be taken for granted.

Comment: @Saad: it means that there is a deleted neighborhood $I$ of $b$ such that $g(t) \neq a$ for all $t\in I$.

Answer (score 1):

A simple version of the substitution rule: Suppose

i) $f$ is defined in a deleted neighborhoood of $a;$

ii) $g$ is a strictly increasing (or strictly decreasing) continuous function defined in a neighborhood of $b,$  with $g(b) = a.$

Then

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L\, \iff \,\lim_{y\to b} f\circ g(y) = L.$$

I'll omit the proof here, except to say the conditions on $g$ imply that we can move back and forth from $a$ to $b$ in the most natural way, using the maps $g$ and $g^{-1}.$

Comment: This is different from what the other question has, which is different from what someone in the comments said.. And I don't think the 3 ways of formulating it are equivalent either. Which one would be the most general? I'd guess the one in the other question since we don't need g to be strictly increasing or decreasing (or even continuous) there..

Comment: @Saad This is the simplest one to use, easiest to understand, and the one you will see most often - all IMHO.

Comment: +1 for framing the conditions in a simple manner. @Saad : you may look at the following answer where I describe the substitution of limits https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073047/72031