# Using a known limit to find an another limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm following a well known Calculus text book to restudy Calculus. One of the example problems in the book asks the following:

Using $$\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin\theta }{\theta}=1,$$ show that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos h-1}{h}=0$$

The answer states that:

Using the formula $\cos h=1-2\sin^2(h/2)$ and
$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos h-1 }{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}-\frac{2\sin^2(h/2)}{h}$

Let $\theta=h/2$,

$$\lim_{h\to 0}-\frac{2sin^2(h/2) }{h}=-\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin(\theta) }{\theta}\sin\theta=-(1)\cdot(0)=0$$

I understand the logic behind this explanation. However, what I don't understand is: how is it possible that the solution claims that:

$$-\lim_{2\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin(\theta) }{\theta}\sin\theta=-\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin(\theta) }{\theta}\sin\theta \ ?$$

I'd be glad if you could help me with this question.
Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: If $2\theta$ goes to $0$ so does $\theta$

Comment: @Dude In fact, $\theta$ goes to $\frac{0}{2}$ :)

Comment: This may be unrelated to the question, but I am only able to recall *one* trigonometric formula: $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$. Try computing the limit with this.

Answer (score 0):

If $2 \theta$ goes to zero, $\theta$ will also go to zero.

Edit: further explanation requested in comments
Hint: 2theta is continous at 0.
More technical explanation ( also  dont wanna be closed as duplicate) [Formal basis for variable substitution in limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167926/formal-basis-for-variable-substitution-in-limits/167948#167948)

Comment: It does provide a rough answer but should be fleshed out into a full explanation.

Comment: I will explain , what more would you like to know?

Comment: Imo, you should attempt to give more detail about why $\theta$ and $2\theta$ can be exchanged in the expression, the fact that multiplication by $2$ is continuous, etc. Basically just write a short paragraph about how it works. The question I'd linked in the comment under the OP question gives more technical details and justification.

Comment: Thank you , I have provided hint and further instruction. Is it ok now or should I add something more?