# Can we always replace $\underset{\delta\rightarrow 0}{\lim}$ with $\underset{k\delta\rightarrow 0}{\lim}$ for $k$ constant?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

Is it in general acceptable to  replace $\underset{\delta\rightarrow 0}{\lim}$ with $\underset{k\delta\rightarrow 0}{\lim}$ for constant $k$?

What I mean by this is, if we have a real-valued function $f$  and we know that, say $\underset{\delta \rightarrow 0}{\lim} f(\delta)=L$ for real constant $k$, is it then valid to say that  $$\underset{\delta \rightarrow 0}{\lim} f(k \delta)=\underset{k\delta \rightarrow 0}{\lim} f(k \delta)=\underset{\delta \rightarrow 0}{\lim} f(\delta)=L\:?$$

(I feel like this should always be the case, because for any constant $k$, $(\delta\rightarrow 0) \Longleftrightarrow (k\delta \rightarrow 0)$ but maybe I'm overlooking something)

Comment: If $k \neq 0$, yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formal basis for variable substitution in limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167926/formal-basis-for-variable-substitution-in-limits)

Comment: However please don't write $\lim_{k\delta \to 0}$. Limit notation always uses just variables under the "lim" and not some expression made of variables.

Comment: For two-sided limits, any *nonzero* constant $k$ will work.  But when a one-sided limit is taken, be careful to ask $k\gt 0$ or else compensate by reversing the side from which we approach the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from scratch: Change $\delta$ to $x$ for clarity. Fix $k\neq 0.$ Suppose $\underset{x \rightarrow 0}{\lim} f(x)=L$. Then, let $\epsilon>0.$ There is a  $\delta>0$ so that if $|x|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon.$ Suppose such a $\delta$ has been produced and that  $|kx|<|k|\delta.$  Set $\delta'=|k|\delta$. Then, if $|kx|<\delta'$ we have  $|kx|<|k|\delta\Rightarrow |x|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. So, with $\delta'$ answering the $\epsilon$-challenge, we have by definition, $\underset{kx \rightarrow 0}{\lim} f(x)=L$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

$\forall k \in \Bbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$,

$$\underset{\delta \rightarrow 0}{\lim} f(\delta)=\underset{k\delta \rightarrow 0}{\lim} f(k \delta)=\underset{t \rightarrow 0}{\lim} f(t)=L$$

where $t=k\delta$

Sometimes be careful with the sign of $k$. It may change a RHL to LHL or vice versa and this creates a problem when the function is not continous

Comment: For the real numbers use `\Bbb{R}`. For set removal use `\setminus` or `\backslash`.

Comment: @K.defaoite noted