# Change of variables in limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, change-of-variable

I've read several answers here on Stackexchange about this, but the actual requirements on $f$ and $g$ are different in different answers, and sometimes in quite substantial ways. Furthermore, I think there are some subtleties here relating to the domains of $f$ and $g$, especially when talking about $g^{-1}$.

I'll begin by giving a motivating example. Suppose we wish to find:
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin(\tan t)}{\tan t}.
$$

What we do is make the substitution $x = \tan t$ and then use that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1.
$$

So what we have is an inner function $g(t) = \tan t$ and an outer function $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$. We're making the claim that if $\lim_{t\to a} g(t) = L$, then
$$
\lim_{t \to a} f(g(t)) = \lim_{g(t) \to L} f(g(t))
$$

My question is about the assumptions on $f$ and $g$ for this to hold. I know that the limit of $g$ at $a$ has to exist. But what about other requirements? I've seen continuity for $f$ be demanded, but also versions where $f$ has *no requirements whatsoever*, but $g$ has to be injective and continuous. Other claims have been that $g$ simply has to be invertible. In particular, for this example $f$ is not continuous at the point of interest.

Comment: How do you define the meaning of$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L?$$

Comment: That the function you will use to change the variable exists.

Comment: I use the standard $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition. If it matters, although I think it's clear from context, I'm talking about strictly real functions of one variable here.

Comment: "I've read several answers here on Stackexchange about this, but the actual requirements on $f$ and $g$ are different in different answers, and sometimes in quite substantial ways." OK, can you cite several answers here on MSE that are confusing you in this regard?

Comment: This: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167926/formal-basis-for-variable-substitution-in-limits
and this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069642/finding-a-limit-using-change-of-variable-how-come-it-works
are two examples.

Comment: Oh, and here's another related document, not from stackexchange though:
https://www3.nd.edu/~math/restricted/CourseArchive/100Level/166/1662000S/Misc/Substitutions.pdf
Here the author requires the function $g$ to be non-constant, but I think he only does that because he wants invertibility.

Comment: There are unfortunately several “standard” definitions in use. Some sources require $f$ to be defined in a punctured interval around $a$, others only require $a$ to be an accumulation point of the domain of $f$. Some use $0<|x-a|<\delta$, others $|x-a|<\delta$. The answer to your question depends very much on these details, so you will need to be more specific.

Comment: I see, then I'll be more specific. Let $f$ be defined in a punctured, open interval around $a$. Then if for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$ whenever $0 < |x-a| < \delta$, then we say that the limit... and so on.