# How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos 7x}{3x^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos 7x}{3x^2}.$$

I solved the problem with the [Taylor series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) expansion of $\cos x$. Here is my solution:

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos 7x}{3x^2}\\ =\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\{1-\frac{(7x)^2}{2!}+\frac{(7x)^4}{4!}-\frac{(7x)^6}{6!}+\dots\}}{3x^2}\\ =\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2(\frac{7^2}{2!}-\frac{7^4x^2}{4!}+\frac{7^6x^4}{6!}-\dots)}{3x^2}\\ =\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{3}(\frac{7^2}{2!}-\frac{7^4x^2}{4!}+\frac{7^6x^4}{6!}-\dots)\\ =\frac {49}{6}$

Can this be solved without using the Taylor series?

Comment: You can use L’Hôspital twice. Or you can use the small angle approximation of cos, but that’s basically the same as Taylor.

Comment: You can write $$
\frac{{1 - \cos (7x)}}{{3x^2 }} = \frac{{49}}{6}\left( {\frac{{\sin \left( {\frac{7}{2}x} \right)}}{{\frac{7}{2}x}}} \right)^2 
$$ using the known identity $
\frac{{1 - \cos w}}{2} = \sin ^2 \left( {\frac{w}{2}} \right)
$.

Comment: Alternative, this is the real part of $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1 - e^{7iz}}{3z^2} = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1 - (1 + 7iz - 49z^2/2 + \cdots)}{3z^2} = \frac{49}{6}$. The series expansion works when $z$ is complex because $e^z$ is an analytic function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Multiplying top and bottom by $1 + \cos 7x$:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos 7x}{3x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\sin 7x)^2}{3x^2} \frac{1}{1 + \cos 7x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\sin 7x)^2}{(7x)^2} \frac{49/3}{1 + \cos 7x} = 1 \cdot \frac{49/3}{2}  = \boxed{\frac{49}{6}}.$$

Comment: (+1) This is the way I would have presented since it avoids LHR and relies on more elementary analytical tools.

Answer (score 8):

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos 7x}{3x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-(1-2\sin^2\frac{7x}{2})}{3x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sin^2\frac{7x}{2}}{3x^2}=\frac{49}{6}.$$

Comment: (+1) for applying elementary analytical tools only.

Answer (score 5):

By L'Hopital's Rule,$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(7x)}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{7\sin(7x)}{6x},$$if this last limit exists. Which it does. You can apply L'Hopital's Rule a second time, or use the fact that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Exactly, I don't see why L'Hopital's can't be used.

Comment: This looks like the simplest solution to me.

Comment: LHR is a bit overkill my friend ;-)

Comment: I don't know L'Hopital's rule. Maybe I've to go through your solution when I learn it :-)

Comment: @Unknown: L'Hôpital's rule states that if $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)=0$, then $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} \, ,$$ *provided that the limit on the RHS exists*.

Comment: For the final limit, we can make the substitution $u=7x$:$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{7\sin(7x)}{6x}=\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{49\sin(u)}{6u}=\frac{49}{6}\cdot\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin u}{u}=\frac{49}{6} \cdot 1=\frac{49}{6} \, .$$

Answer (score 4):

Use l'hopital. The derivative of the numerator is $(1-\cos 7x)'=7\sin 7x$ and of the denominator $(3x^2)=6x$. We get
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{7\sin(7x)}{6x}=\lim_{x/7\to0}\frac{7\sin(x)}{6(x/7)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{49\sin(x)}{6x}=\frac{49}{6}.$$
In the second step we used the substitution $x\mapsto x/7$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167926/formal-basis-for-variable-substitution-in-limits) why it's justified.

Comment: $$(1-\cos 7x)' = 7\sin 7x$$ not $7\sin x$

Comment: Sorry for the typo, now corrected. (At least in the limit it was correct.)

Comment: LHR is a bit overkill ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It is already known that:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Now Manipulating,

$$=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos 7x}{3x^2}.\frac{49}{49}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos 7x}{(7x)^2}.\frac{49}{3}$$

$$=\frac{49}{3\cdot2}=\frac{49}{6}$$

Answer (score 2):

An asymptotic approach

As $x \to 0$

$$\frac{1-\cos 7x}{3x^2} \sim \frac{49x^2/2}{3x^2}=\frac{49}{6}$$