# How can I see that $(\frac{1}{\cos x})^{\cos x}$ goes to 1 for x that goes to $\frac{\pi}{2}^{-}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

The limit generate an uncertain form of the type $[\infty^{0}]$ and that is pretty much I can say about it.

I know that $\cos x$ goes to $\frac{\pi}{2}^{-}$ as $-x+\frac{\pi}{2}$ but I do not see how it helps in moving away from $[\infty^{0}]$.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Takes the logarithm, and turn it into the form $\infty/\infty$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the substitution [$y=\cos(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167926/formal-basis-for-variable-substitution-in-limits) you get: $$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}^-}\left(\frac{1}{cos(x)}\right)^{\cos(x)}=\lim_{y\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)^y =\lim_{y\to 0^+}(y)^{-y}.$$ Using the continuity of logarithm we get: $$\ln(\lim_{y\to 0^+}(y)^{-y})= \lim_{y\to 0^+}\ln((y)^{-y})=\lim_{y\to 0^+}-y\ln(y)=\lim_{y\to 0^+}-\frac {\ln y}{\frac{1}{y}}\stackrel{\text{L'Hôpital's rule}}{=}0$$
$\implies \ln(\lim_{y\to 0^+}(y)^{-y})=0\implies \lim_{y\to 0^+}(y)^{-y}=1$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go beyond the limit, let $x=\frac \pi  2-t$.

$$y=\big(\csc(t) \big)^{\sin(t)}\quad \implies \log(y)=\sin(t)\,\log\big(\csc(t) \big)$$ Now, using Taylor around $t=0^+$
$$\csc(t)=\frac{1}{t}+\frac{t}{6}+\frac{7 t^3}{360}+O\left(t^5\right)$$
$$\log\big(\csc(t) \big)=-\log (t)+\frac{t^2}{6}+\frac{t^4}{180}+O\left(t^6\right)$$ Multiply by the usual series expansion of $\sin(t)$
$$\log(y)=-t \log (t)+\frac{1}{6} t^3 (\log (t)+1)-\frac{1}{360} t^5 (3   \log (t)+8)+O\left(t^7\right)$$
Now
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=1-t \log (t)+\frac{1}{2} t^2 \log ^2(t)+\cdots$$

[Compare](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B%7BCsc%5Bt%5D%5ESin%5Bt%5D%2C1-t+Log%5Bt%5D%2B1%2F2+t%5E2+Log%5Bt%5D%5E2%7D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C0.5%7D%5D) the plots to see how good (or bad) is the approximation