# Simplifying $f(n)$ by substituting, for $n$, an appropriately chosen function $n(x)$ to observe limiting behaviour of $f(n)$. Is this justified?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Say, I'm comparing two functions 

$f(n) = (ln(n))^2$ and $ g(n) = n^{0.01}$

as $n \rightarrow  \infty$, by evaluating 

 
$\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty }  \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty }  \frac{ln(n)^2}{n^{0.01}} $.

**My question:**

Am I justified in simplifying this by expressing $n$ as a function of $x \in \Re$, such that 

$n(x) = e^x$,

 
so that the original limit becomes 

 
$\lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty }  \frac{f(n(x))}{g(n(x))} = \lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty }  \frac{x^2}{e^{0.01x}} $ ?

Comment: For the functions that you see most commonly, that would be OK.  Be careful when the functions vary a lot near $\infty$, such as $(x+\sin(x))/\cos(x)$.  But, for simple functions like exponentials and powers, it'll work.

Comment: There is a complete discussion about the circumstances in which you can do this type of substitution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/53703/742).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $n=e^x$ is monotone, so it's justified. In this specific example you don't need to do it:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log^a n}{n^s} = 0
$$

where $a,s>0$

Comment: I see. So $n(x)$ can be any monotone function?

Comment: yes, I think so.